# C++ implementation of basic_string

Tags: c++, strings

This is a `basic_string` implementation that has SSO. It's not done, but the fundamental operations are all there (`append`, `erase`, `resize`, `reserve`, `push_back`/`pop_back`). Proper iterators and my own `char_traits` impl will be added eventually.

```
#include <string>

template<typename CharType, typename Traits = std::char_traits<CharType>, typename Allocator = std::allocator<CharType>>
class kbasic_string
{
public:
  static const size_t npos = -1;
  using iterator = CharType*;
  using const_iterator = const CharType*;

  friend kbasic_string operator+(const kbasic_string& lhs, const kbasic_string& rhs)
  {
    return kbasic_string{lhs}.append(rhs);
  }

  friend kbasic_string operator+(const kbasic_string& lhs, const CharType* rhs)
  {
    return kbasic_string{lhs}.append(rhs);
  }

  friend kbasic_string operator+(const kbasic_string& lhs, CharType rhs)
  {
    return kbasic_string{lhs}.append(rhs);
  }

  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& lhs, const kbasic_string& rhs)
  {
    lhs.write(rhs.data(), rhs.size());
    return lhs;
  }

  friend std::wostream& operator<<(std::wostream& lhs, const kbasic_string& rhs)
  {
    lhs.write(rhs.data(), rhs.size());
    return lhs;
  }

  kbasic_string() = default;

  kbasic_string(const kbasic_string& other)
  {
    reserve(other.capacity_);
    if (other.size_)
      std::copy(other.begin(), other.end() + 1, begin());
    size_ = other.size_;
  }

  kbasic_string(kbasic_string&& other)
  {
    if (other.on_heap())
    {
      std::memcpy(&data_, &other.data_, sizeof(CharType*));
      std::memset(&other.data_, 0, sizeof(CharType*));
    }
    else
    {
      std::copy(other.begin(), other.end() + 1, begin());
    }
    size_ = other.size_;
    capacity_ = other.capacity_;
    on_heap_ = other.on_heap_;
    other.on_heap_ = false;
  }

  kbasic_string& operator=(const kbasic_string& other)
  {
    reserve(other.capacity_);
    if (other.size_)
      std::copy(other.begin(), other.end() + 1, begin());
    size_ = other.size_;
    return *this;
  }

  kbasic_string& operator=(kbasic_string&& other)
  {
    if (other.on_heap())
    {
      std::memcpy(&data_, &other.data_, sizeof(CharType*));
      std::memset(&other.data_, 0, sizeof(CharType*));
      on_heap_ = true;
    }
    else
    { 
      std::copy(other.begin(), other.end() + 1, begin());
    }
    size_ = other.size_;
    capacity_ = other.capacity_;
    other.on_heap_ = false;
    return *this;
  }

  kbasic_string(const CharType* str)
  {
    size_t size = Traits::length(str);
    if (size > capacity_)
      reserve(size);
    std::copy(str, str + size + 1, data());
    size_ = size;
  }

  kbasic_string& operator=(const CharType* str)
  {
    size_t size = Traits::length(str);
    if (size > capacity_)
      reserve(size);
    std::copy(str, str + size + 1, data());
    size_ = size;
  }

  void reserve(size_t capacity)
  {
    if (capacity <= capacity_ || capacity <= 22)
      return;
    Allocator alloc;
    CharType* mem = alloc.allocate(capacity + 1);
    if (size_)
      std::copy(begin(), end() + 1, mem);
    if (on_heap())
      alloc.deallocate(data(), capacity_ + 1);
    else
      on_heap_ = true;
    std::memcpy(data_, &mem, sizeof(CharType*));
    capacity_ = capacity;
  }

  void resize(size_t size, CharType app)
  {
    if (size > size_)
    {
      reserve(size);
      std::fill(end(), end() + (size - size_), app);
      *(end() + (size - size_) + 1) = 0;
    }
    else if (size < size_)
    {
      erase(end() - (size_ - size), end());
    } 
    else
    {
      return;
    }
    size_ = size;
  }

  void resize(size_t size)
  {
    resize(size, 0);
  }

  template<typename Iter, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::_Is_iterator_v<Iter>>>
  kbasic_string& erase(Iter first, Iter last)
  {
    return erase(first - begin(), last - first);
  }

  kbasic_string& erase(size_t pos, size_t count)
  {
    if (pos > size_)
      throw std::out_of_range("pos is out of range");
    std::copy(begin() + pos + count, end() + 1, begin() + pos);
    size_ -= count;
    return *this;
  }

  template<typename Iter, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::_Is_iterator_v<Iter>>>
  kbasic_string& erase(Iter it)
  {
    return erase(it - begin(), 1);
  }

  void pop_back()
  {
    erase(end() - 1);
  }

  void clear()
  {
    erase(begin(), end());
  }

  kbasic_string& append(const CharType* str, size_t len)
  {
    if (size_ + len > capacity_)
      reserve(size_ + len);
    std::copy(str, str + len + 1, begin() + size_);
    size_ += len;
    return *this;
  }

  kbasic_string& append(const CharType* str)
  {
    return append(str, Traits::length(str));
  }

  kbasic_string& append(const kbasic_string& str)
  {
    return append(str.data());
  }

  kbasic_string& append(CharType ch)
  {
    if (size_ + 1 > capacity_)
      reserve(size_ + 1);
    iterator prev_end = begin() + size_;
    *prev_end = ch;
    *(prev_end + 1) = 0;
    ++size_;
    return *this;
  }

  template<typename Iter, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::_Is_iterator_v<Iter>>>
  kbasic_string& append(Iter first, Iter last)
  {
    if (last - first > capacity_)
      reserve(last - first);
    std::copy(first, last, begin() + size_);
    return *this;
  }

  void push_back(CharType ch)
  {
    append(ch);
  }

  CharType* data() noexcept
  {
    return on_heap() ? heap_ptr() : data_;
  }

  const CharType* data() const noexcept
  {
    return on_heap() ? heap_ptr() : data_;
  }

  size_t size() const noexcept
  {
    return size_;
  }

  size_t length() const noexcept
  {
    return size_;
  }

  size_t capacity() const noexcept
  {
    return capacity_;
  }

  iterator begin() noexcept
  {
    return data();
  }

  const_iterator begin() const noexcept
  {
    return data();
  }

  iterator end() noexcept
  {
    return data() + size_;
  }

  const_iterator end() const noexcept
  {
    return data() + size_;
  }

  bool empty() const noexcept
  {
    return !size_;
  }

  CharType& at(size_t n)
  {
    return data()[n];
  }

  const CharType& at(size_t n) const
  {
    return data()[n];
  }

  CharType& operator[](size_t n)
  {
    return at(n);
  }

  const CharType& operator[](size_t n) const
  {
    return at(n);
  }

  kbasic_string& operator+=(const kbasic_string& other)
  {
    return append(other);
  }

  kbasic_string& operator+=(const CharType* str)
  {
    return append(str);
  }
  kbasic_string& operator+=(CharType ch)
  {
    return append(ch);
  }

  bool operator==(const kbasic_string& other)
  {
    return std::equal(begin(), end(), other.begin(), other.end());
  }

  bool operator==(const CharType* str)
  {
    return std::equal(begin(), end(), str, str + Traits::length(str));
  }

  bool operator==(CharType ch)
  {
    return size_ == 1 && *begin() == ch;
  }

  bool operator!=(const kbasic_string& other)
  {
    return !(*this == other);
  }

  bool operator!=(const CharType* str)
  {
    return !(*this == str);
  }

  bool operator!=(CharType ch)
  {
    return !(*this == ch);
  }

  ~kbasic_string()
  {
    if (on_heap())
      Allocator{}.deallocate(data(), capacity_ + 1);
  }

private:
  bool on_heap() const
  {
    return on_heap_;
  }

  const CharType* heap_ptr() const
  {
    CharType* ptr = nullptr;
    std::memcpy(&ptr, data_, sizeof(CharType*));
    return ptr;
  }

  CharType* heap_ptr()
  {
    CharType* ptr = nullptr;
    std::memcpy(&ptr, data_, sizeof(CharType*));
    return ptr;
  }

  size_t size_ = 0;
  size_t capacity_ = 22;
  bool on_heap_ = false;
  CharType data_[23] = {0};
};
```

Comment: a small thing:  since is c++ it should be std::size_t not size_t

Answer (score 8):

It's tricky to review something like this where you're imitating an overcomplicated design, so you *know* certain things are unimplemented (such as iterators), but then other things might also be unimplemented by accident. For example:

- You take a parameter `Traits = std::char_traits<CharType>` but then you don't use it! The real `basic_string` would use the traits class for things like where you use `std::copy`.
- You take an allocator parameter `Allocator = std::allocator<CharType>` and do use it, kind of, but you don't go through `std::allocator_traits<Allocator>`. Since all you use is `a.allocate()` and `a.deallocate()`, this is probably fine in all real-world situations; but really you should be using `allocator_traits`. It can't hurt.
- You don't store an `Allocator` data member of `kbasic_string`; instead, you default-construct one *ex nihilo* every time you want to use the allocator. This (plus the previous bullet point, technically) means that your container is not *allocator-aware*: it won't work with user-defined allocators or allocators such as `std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<char>`. You get away with it in your tests right now only because `std::allocator<char>` is (A) empty and (B) default-constructible.
- You do have tests, right?

---

```
  std::memcpy(&data_, &other.data_, sizeof(CharType*));
  std::memset(&other.data_, 0, sizeof(CharType*));
```

This is a very strange way of writing

```
  data_ = other.data_;
  other.data_ = nullptr;
```

...oh, I see, your `data_` is a `char[23]`, not a `char *`. Well, okay. I would strongly recommend making it a `union` of `char[23]` and `char *` so that you can copy the pointer member without weird type-punning tricks.

Pedantic nit: Setting all-bits-zero is not technically the same thing as setting to `nullptr` — the in-memory representation of `nullptr` need not be all-bits-zero (even though, in practice, it will be).

Also, notice that to be *allocator-aware* you will have to store a pointer of type `std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::pointer`, which you *definitely* cannot assume is all-bits-zero when it's null! For example, `boost::interprocess::offset_ptr<char>` is not all-bits-zero when it's null.

---

```
bool operator==(const kbasic_string& other)
```

Here and throughout, you forgot the trailing `const`. These days I recommend making every operator an "ADL friend" non-member:

```
friend bool operator==(const kbasic_string& other, const kbasic_string& other) {
    return std::equal(begin(), end(), other.begin(), other.end());
}
```

Then it's really obvious if you forget one of the two `const`s.

---

```
  template<typename Iter, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::_Is_iterator_v<Iter>>>
  kbasic_string& append(Iter first, Iter last)
  {
    if (last - first > capacity_)
      reserve(last - first);
    std::copy(first, last, begin() + size_);
    return *this;
  }
```

Write a test case for this function! For example, `string("123456789").append(a, a+3)`. There's a bug in the `if` condition that leads quickly to undefined behavior.

```
kbasic_string& append(const kbasic_string& str)
{
    return append(str.data());
}
```

Also write tests for this function! Since `str` knows its own `size()`, does it make sense to throw away that information here? What happens if `str` contains an embedded `'\0'` character — what is `string("abc").append(string("d\0e", 3))`?

---

Your use of `std::_Is_iterator_v<Iter>` is sketchy. I would recommend writing your own portable type-trait, something like this:

```
template<class, class = void> struct is_iterator : std::false_type {};
template<class T> struct is_iterator<T, decltype(void(std::iterator_traits<T>::iterator_category{}))> : std::true_type {};
```

Orthogonally, you seem to be using `_Is_iterator_v` almost like pseudocode that magically does whatever you want done. Here you use it to mean "is an input iterator or better":

```
template<typename Iter, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::_Is_iterator_v<Iter>>>
kbasic_string& append(Iter first, Iter last)
```

Here you use it to mean "is either `kbasic_string::iterator` or `kbasic_string::const_iterator`":

```
template<typename Iter, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::_Is_iterator_v<Iter>>>
kbasic_string& erase(Iter it)
```

`erase` should certainly be rewritten as a non-template:

```
kbasic_string& erase(const_iterator it)
```

---

Finally, consider whether you could save space by replacing every instance of `on_heap_` with the condition `(capacity_ > 22)`. And consider moving the magic number 22 into a variable!

```
static constexpr size_t SBO_CAPACITY = 22;
size_t size_ = 0;
size_t capacity_ = SBO_CAPACITY;
CharType data_[SBO_CAPACITY + 1] = {0};
```

Answer (score 3):

I was looking at a method which I considered to be really easy: `c_str`, however, it doesn't look that easy based on how you implemented it.

Currently, you have a bool indicating whether you should store it on the heap or not. If you replace that by a pointer to the first character. You could implement the `onHeap` by comparing 2 pointers. Every access to the characters can simply use the pointer, unless for the appending.